# How to export/write 3D polyline of geometry type '3D Line String' or `3D Multi Line String' as shapefile in R?

Tags: r, 3d, gis, geospatial

I tried exporting the 3D polyline to shapefile using the `st_write()`. I got the following error.

```
Creating or updating layer out failed.
Error in CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver, as.character(dataset_options),  : 
  Write error.
In addition: Warning message:
In CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver, as.character(dataset_options),  :
  GDAL Error 6: Geometry type of `3D Multi Line String' not supported in shapefiles.  Type can be overridden with a layer creation option of SHPT=POINT/ARC/POLYGON/MULTIPOINT/POINTZ/ARCZ/POLYGONZ/MULTIPOINTZ/MULTIPATCH.
```

After a bit of googling I'm still not able to find a solution. Any help appreciated.
Below is a reproducible code.

```
library(sf)
g1 = st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(0,1,2),c(0,2,3))))
sd = st_sf(geometry=st_sfc(g1), crs=27700)
st_write(sd, "out.shp")
```

Comment: Try `st_write("out.shp", layer_options = "SHPT=ARCZ")`

Comment: Where was the `layer_options = 'SHPT=ARCZ')` found, ie. down in the driver docs?

Comment: @Chris The error message itself is explanatory, just that I missed interpreting it. "Type can be overridden with a layer creation option of SHPT=POINT/ARC/POLYGON/MULTIPOINT/POINTZ/ARCZ/POLYGONZ/MULTIPOINTZ/MULTIPATCH"

Comment: @Chris, the source is the error message itself and gdal drivers page: https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html#vector-shapefile